# Canada tax on cash gift from abroad

Tags: canada, gift-tax

I am a new immigrant in Canada, I received cash gift transferred to my bank account in Canada from my family members abroad for supporting my life in Canada. Is this cash gift received taxable ?

Answer (score 1):

No, not taxable.

From [Canada Revenue](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/nttxd-eng.html):

> You do not have to report certain amounts in your income, including
>   the following: . . most gifts and inheritances;